# How can I apply an actionlistener to my timer?

Tags: java, timer, actionlistener

I am trying to link an actionlistener to a timer for a game I am writing. Whenever the timer fires, monsters in a 2D array randomly move to one adjacent tile. The array is not completely full of monsters. Where there aren't monsters, my array has null.

Here's what I have so far:

```
private class MonsterListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Level.SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Level.SIZE; j++) {
                if (monsters[i][j] != null) {
                    monsters[i][j].update();
                }
            }
        }
        updateState();
    }
}
```

And inside my Monster class:

```
public void update() {
        rand1 = new Random();
        rand2 = new Random();
        drow = rand1.nextInt(3); //random int 0,1,2
        dcol = rand2.nextInt(3); //random int 0,1,2
        drow -= 1; //random int -1,0,1
        dcol -= 1; //random int -1,0,1

        row += drow;
        col += dcol;
    }
```

When I create my timer, I do this

```
public final int DELAY = 1000;
Timer myTimer = new Timer(DELAY, new MonsterListener());
```

However, I keep getting an error that reads

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Timer(int,Game.MonsterListener)
location: class java.util.Timer
    myTimer = new Timer(DELAY, listener);
                      ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `javax.swing.Timer` instead of `java.util.Timer`

[I suspect this because you are using `ActionListener`]

Comment: I believe you are right! Another question on the subject. Is there any way  to access this timer from another class for the same project? I want my GUI to update every time this timer fires, but the timer isn't in the panel class I have that updates the GUI, so is there any way inside my panel class that I can just say "when timer fires, do this..."?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your project organization completely. However, if you want to associate a timer with each instance of the panel, you could create and set a timer in the constructor of the panel.